# can anyone tell me the javascript equalent for this

Tags: javascript, html

```
var demo, fixedTable;
fixedTable = function(el) {
    var $body, $header, $sidebar;
    $body = $(el).find('.fixedTable-body');
    $sidebar = $(el).find('.fixedTable-sidebar table');
    $header = $(el).find('.fixedTable-header table');
    return $($body).scroll(function() {
      $($sidebar).css('margin-top', -$($body).scrollTop());
      return$($header).css('marginleft',-$($body).scrollLeft());
    });};
demo = new fixedTable($('#demo'));
```

My version of javascript, but encountered some errors

```
fixedTable = function(el) {
   var body, header, sidebar;
       body = el.querySelectorAll('fixedTable-body');
       sidebar = el.querySelectorAll('fixedTable-sidebar table');
       header = el.querySelectorAll('fixedTable-header table');
       return body.onscroll = function() {
         sidebar.getElementById("pivot_table").style.marginTop = -body.scrollTop;
         return header.style.marginLeft =  -body.scrollLeft;
       };
     }

 demo = new fixedTable(document.getElementById('demo'));
```

above code is to make the header and sidebar of a table constant while scrolling

// three parts of table body containing table cell with value , header - with table headers , sidebar - containing row heading.

I'm trying to create a pivot table.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code translation service. Please make an effort to convert the code yourself first. If you run into problems, you can then post the code you've written, explain the problem you've encountered, and ask a specific question.

Comment: You mean the JavaScript equivalent of the [Whitespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_(programming_language)) program hidden behind that esoteric formatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `.` at selector at

```
 body = el.querySelectorAll('.fixedTable-body'); 
 sidebar = el.querySelectorAll('.fixedTable-sidebar table');
 header = el.querySelectorAll('.fixedTable-header table');
```

Comment: like body = el.querySelectorAll('.fixedTable-body'); ?

Comment: @yureka Yes. One method of selecting an element by `.className` is prefixing selector with `.`, which is present a jQuery version; see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors